# Alternative to global variables in a single Flask routes.py (20 variables across 5 functions)

Tags: flask

I've written an app that has worked ok in development on my laptop.
Its all in a single routes.py and uses around 20 global variables between the various functions.

As well as using global variables i've been also passing to HTML like this, which seems to work ok.

`return render_template('graph.html', labels=line_labels)` etc

But now I've come to deploy the app using uwsgi on a live VM the same code now crashes after the first redirect.

`NameError: name 'no_of_slots' is not defined`

So it looks like global variables don't work the same using  uwsgi?  The variables aren't being passed or kept.

And a quick search around here suggests global variables are a bad thing.
Am I right in thinking they could get passed between different users using the website?  If so, that is bad.

In my situation, ie I just want to store some single entry variables that all the functions can use as well as some dicts for graph data etc.

What would be the best method?   One that will scale in a multi user website?

Is sessions a potential way forward?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### **Do not use global variables in Flask app.**

---

**Storing static variables**

If you need to store static variables that do not change during runtime and are used in multiple places. It's preferable to store them in the config object. [Flask Docs: Configuration Handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/).

You instantiate them through a cfg file or whatever and then, access them through the config object within the *app* object (if you have it) or its proxy *current_app*.

```
from flask import current_app

def malfunction(a, b):
    current_app.config.get("MY_VAR", None)
    # or
    current_app.config["MY_VAR"]
```

**Storing dynamic variable**

If you need to store dynamic variables, use the application context. [Flask Docs: The Application Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#storing-data).

The *g* object is for storing global data from one function to another within *the same request*, and is not at all for sharing data between requests.

[Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/), you can find a good example of the usage of *g* for define and access the database in the official example [Flaskr](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/introduction/).

**Share variables between requests**

If you need to share variables in different requests but in the same session. Then you can use the session object from Flask. [Flask Docs: Sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions)

**Share variables between user**

At this point, you need backend storage, like Redis, Memcached, or database. There is a lot of different extensions to handle that, depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you. So to clarify.

Variables than span between requests, use sessions ie session["sum_total"]

Variables between functions, but for the same request, use g ie g.sum_total

Variables that don't leave the function, use standard variable naming? ie sum_total

Time to rewrite my code. :)